# Regex to capute single backslash with single space after

Tags: regex

I have trouble with figuring out this regex: 
https://regex101.com/r/WtAYVa/2

It works capturing the first single backslash (`\`), but I want to ignore (`\\`), especially, when there's a space after `\\`.

Comment: Try `(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)`

Comment: So you want to capture a backslash followed by a space, but only when the whole isn't preceded by another backslash? In that case if your language supports lookbehinds, `(?<!\\)\\ ` (with a space at the end)

Comment: @Aaron, But isn't \\\\ = \\, and \\ = \, i.e. escaping.

Comment: Sure is. My regex reads as follow : check that the previous character isn't a backslash. If so, match a backslash followed by a space. I wouldn't be surprised if I had missed parts of your requirements though, can't say your were very explicit.

Comment: Well, `(?<!\\)\\ ` might be exactly what you need. What is the programming language?

Comment: @Wiktior Pyton.

Comment: Ok, `re.findall(r'(?<!\\)\\ ', s)`? `re.sub(r'(?<!\\)\\ ', '', s)`? Use `r'...'`, raw string literals so that you do not have to use 4 backslashes to match 1 backslash.

Comment: @Aaron, "can't say your were very explicit", I was just thinking from a general point of understanding. I.e. it's common to deal with char escaping in regexes, especially, when used in some programming languages.

Comment: Well, one more example string with expected output would make your question clearer

Comment: I was talking about the original question rather than the comment, of which I totally missed the point. I didn't remember python's standard strings would have needed 4 consecutive backslashes to represent a literal backslash (definitely use `r"..."`)

Comment: So, which pattern worked for you?

Comment: Both of you did correct. Interestingly, someone else posted an answer as well. So I am not sure, you are all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we wish to fail the double backslash, and only pass the single one, we would be simply adding more boundaries to our expression, such as we would be using start and end anchors:

```
^\\\s$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZU49tX/1)